# How to use SCIPoptSuite with UG(FiberSCIP)?

Tags: scip, scipopt

I an using SCIPoptSuite in my code to solve a MINLP problem, and I would like to test if parallelization inproves the performance or not.

However the UG Framework is not built in the SCIPoptSuite installer version, so I wonder if I can compile UG separately and link it with SCIPoptSuite?

Or must I compile SCIPoptSuite from source code, where I can link UG directly? (But that means i need to install IpOpt and link it as well, since I need IpOpt too and it is included in the installer version).

Answer (score 0):

For now the UG framework is not distributed in the precompiled packages, but hopefully it will soon be.
In principle you just need to set a symlink in the UG repository pointing to the SCIP library. But I am afraid in your case you will have to compile SCIP again, with the PARASCIP flag set to true. Then you can compile UG as described in its README.